# Internal user access to community record link

Tags: community, url

I am working on a requirement where I need to update the link of the attachment to a field in the parent record. I have used "getSalesforceBaseUrl" to get the URL and updated the attachment link in the parent field. It's working fine except one case. If a community user uploads the document, then URL on parent records gets the base URL for communities. As a result of this, when internal click on the document URL, SF ask internal users to login in the community to access the document. How to overcome this case.

I have tried using the `Allow internal users to login directly to the community option on the Login & Registration page in Community Management.` but it's not working. Still, internal is being asked to login in the community if he/she clicks on document link.

Comment: any help or idea is appreciated.